# My input isn't passing the text like I want

Tags: javascript, html

**Hello, guys!**

I'm new at coding and I tried to do a "implementation" of a project from freeCodeCamp to a independent HTMl project, but I'm having a big issue withtout knowing why. The button is working and I think the string has been picked up but the code didnt reply, the most strange thing is that in the compiler of freeCodeCamp it works.

I need help! look at
My code

```js
// This is a script from a palindrome checker, in freeCodeCamp; has been turned on a website checker.

function palindrome() {
  var verify = [];

  alert("the problem isn't button")
  
  // Variables from HTML

  var str = document.getElementById("palind").value;

  // Ignore symbols and replace it, looking only at letters/numbers

  var pieces = str
    .toLowerCase()
    .replaceAll("-", "")
    .replaceAll("_", "")
    .replaceAll('/', "")
    .replaceAll("(", ")")
    .replaceAll(".", '')
    .replaceAll(",", "")
    .replaceAll(" ", '')
    .split('')


  // For loop verify if has symmetry in the letters

  for (let i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
    if (pieces[0 + i] == pieces[(pieces.length - 1) - i]) {
      verify.push(true);
    } else {
      verify.push(false);
    }
  }

  // Conditional replies 

  if (verify.includes(false)) {
    alert("Nope, this isn't a palindrome!");
  }
  if (verify.includes(true)) {
    alert("Yes, this is a palindrome!");
  } else {
    alert("Invalid entry");
  }
}
```

```css
#palind {
  color: black;
}

#clickme {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Hahmlet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Palindrome</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="palindrome.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <forms>
      <input id="palind" type="text" placeholder="Input your palindrome:" required>
      <p>This is a palindrome?</p>
      <input id="clickme" type="button" value="Check It!" onclick="palindrome()" />
    </forms>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve] here, not a link. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Please put code in the question

Comment: You also need to explain what the code is supposed to do, and what it's doing wrong more clearly.

Comment: Could you please update the title of the question to be a summary of what you're trying to ask, that will make it easier for people browsing to decide whether this question is something can answer or is something that might contain an answer useful to them. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Barmar thank you for solving my issue with the stackoverflow. I used de crtl + k but it didnt work like I have imaginted. I will try to do it better in my next post. :)

Comment: @JVDL sure i will!

Comment: What do you mean by "the code didn't reply"? I entered `abcde` and clicked the button. First it said it's not a palindrome, then it said it's a palindrome. The value of `verify` is `[false, false, true, false, false]`, so it meets both `verify.includes()` conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, the problem is that if you don‘t enter a palindrome, first „Nope“ pops up, and then „Yes“ comes up.

To fix this issue, you can add a `break` statement at the end of the lines showing the results of the checks to stop the function execution. Your JS would look like this at the end:

```
// Conditional replies 

  if (verify.includes(false)) {
    alert("Nope, this isn't a palindrome!");
    break;
  }
  if (verify.includes(true)) {
    alert("Yes, this is a palindrome!");
    break;
  } else {
    alert("Invalid entry");
  }
```

This will show the result, and then exit the function to prevent further execution. Another approach would be to replace the second `if` statement with an `else if` statement like this:

`// Conditional replies`

```
if (verify.includes(false)) {
    alert("Nope, this isn't a palindrome!");
  }
  else if (verify.includes(true)) {
    alert("Yes, this is a palindrome!");
  } else {
    alert("Invalid entry");
  }
```

I hope I could help you,
wish you much fun learning programming

Comment: Thank you for the commitment!
Now I have fixed the issues and it works fine.

Thank you for the help, I hope you are having great times nowadays <3